# A good and comprehensive book about Set Theory?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a good text in intermediate set theory?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25734/what-is-a-good-text-in-intermediate-set-theory)

I need a good book about Set Theory. As I was searching online I came across "Set Theory - Kenneth Kunen" which seems to be one of the bests. Does anyone have any other suggestions? Should I be concerned about reading something which is written recently or old texts are also good?

Comment: *Set Theory with Applications* by **T.Lin and F.Lin** is an old one but is a good for start.

Comment: Depending on your background, you might first consider going through the very good *Naive Set Theory*, by Halmos.

Comment: @André: I don’t much care for Halmos: it’s a bit too old-fashioned. My recommendation for a serious beginner is Hrbacek & Jech, [Introduction to Set Theory](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Revised-Expanded-Chapman-Mathematics/dp/0824779150).

Comment: I second for Hrbacek & Jech's book too.

Comment: Me too (my review is on amazon).

Comment: I third it and mentions Keith Devlin Joy of Sets

Answer (score 6):

The best book I've seen on set theory for the serious student is Yiannis Moschovakis' *Notes on Set Theory* . Deep, broad and beautifully written with lots of good exercises. It's the book I wish I'd known about when I was taking Russell Miller's set theory course at CUNY. The old standby which I actually did use for the course is Herbert Enderton's *Elements of Set Theory*. This book is also beautifully written, but is deeper in a number of respects and Enderton is sometimes confusing since he isn't clear sometimes on the distinction between a set, it's subsets and it's elements. 
  (To be honest, though, this is not so much a failing of Enderton's book, but of axiomatic set theory in general when it is presented in natural language rather then mathematical logical language. But that's the great chicken-or-the-egg debate of axiomatic set theory: logic first or no logic?) 
 There's a few others,but those are my faves.

Comment: OK,I AM BEGINNING TO LOSE MY TEMPER WITH PEOPLE DOWNVOTING MY POSTS JUST FOR KICKS AND ANONYMOUSLY AT THAT.I'M FILING A COMPLAINT WITH THE MODERATORS.

Comment: I did not down-vote (I was just looking at some closed questions), but I would imagine that the reason someone down-voted may be one of the following: namedropping ("Russell Miller's set theory course at CUNY...") is not only irrelevant but also is not considered in good form; your answer begins to ramble a bit (you begin to criticize set theory in an answer, which is not really related to OP's question).  Like I said, I don't have a huge problem with this stuff, but that's probably why someone down-voted.  Also, I prefer Enderton over Moschovaski, but I'm not a huge fan of set theory.  =]

Comment: @james Personal recollections are part of the humanity of mathematics. Paul Halmos' I WANT TO BE A MATHEMATICIAN burned that into my psyche for life. Mathematics isn't just about number,functions and symbols-it's about the humans you learned it from.